# How to serialize a machine learning model into a JSON file

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, serialization, pickle

I have build a machine learning model using `xgboost.XGBClassifier` in python. I am using `pickle` to serialize the model right now but would like to have a json file of this model, too. How can I do it?

So, basically I have this code :

```
from xgboost import XGBClassifier
import pickle
import pandas as pd

# read data
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', sep='\t')

# features and target : 
X = df.drop(columns=['target'],axis=1)
Y = df['target']

# split the data
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.3, random_state=0)

model = XGBClassifier().fit(X_train,Y_train)

pickle_out = open("pickle_file.pkl","wb")
pickle.dump(model, pickle_out)
pickle_out.close()
```

Comment: Guess I need to write a function. Searching how.

Comment: did you try `yaml` here example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50846431/converting-a-yaml-file-to-python-json-object/50846530

Comment: Why use JSON when you've got h5py available?

Answer (score 2):

It's actually supported out of the box (as an experimental feature) from 1.0.0 onwards. See https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/saving_model.html

It's simply using a json as the extension for the output file.

```
model.save_model('model_file_name.json')
```

You may want to save hyperparameters in a seperate json file.