# Convert hydra/omegaconf config to python nested dict/list?

Tags: python, fb-hydra, omegaconf

I'd like to convert a OmegaConf/Hydra config to a nested dictionary/list. How can I do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting a YAML file to Python JSON object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50846431/converting-a-yaml-file-to-python-json-object)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

See [OmegaConf.to_container()](https://omegaconf.readthedocs.io/en/2.1_branch/usage.html#omegaconf-to-container).

Usage snippet:

```py
>>> conf = OmegaConf.create({"foo": "bar", "foo2": "${foo}"})
>>> assert type(conf) == DictConfig
>>> primitive = OmegaConf.to_container(conf)
>>> show(primitive)
type: dict, value: {'foo': 'bar', 'foo2': '${foo}'}
>>> resolved = OmegaConf.to_container(conf, resolve=True)
>>> show(resolved)
type: dict, value: {'foo': 'bar', 'foo2': 'bar'}
```

Comment: Snippet: `from omegaconf import OmegaConf; OmegaConf.to_container(cfg)`

Comment: Added usage snippet to answer.

Comment: wonder why resolve=True is not the default.

Comment: resolving interpolations is a destructive operation that is changing the semantics of the config. e.g. modifying foo in the original config will change both foo and foo2 but it does not hold the same way after you resolve.

Answer (score 5):

One can simply convert from omegaconf to python dictionary by **dict()**. Follow the example given below:

```
>>> type(config)
<class 'omegaconf.dictconfig.DictConfig'>
>>> config
{'host': '0.0.0.0', 'port': 8000, 'app': 'main:app', 'reload': False, 'debug': False}
>>> dict(config)
{'host': '0.0.0.0', 'port': 8000, 'app': 'main:app', 'reload': False, 'debug': False}
>>> type(dict(config))
<class 'dict'>
```

Comment: This does not convert nested DictConfig objects inside the top-level object